# Body Params for array of Int using Django REST Swagger

Tags: python, django, rest, swagger

I have configured `Swagger` to work with my `Django` and `REST` framework project using pip. I'm on `djangorestframework==3.3.3`, `django-rest-swagger==0.3.7` and `Django==1.9.6`.

I am using `Swagger` docs to test my API but one particular endpoint (which expects an array of integers as params in it's body) keeps throwing errors. The error is `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Currently this is what i have in my `views.py` the `PUT` endpoint:

```
def put(self, request, pk):
    """
        ---
        parameters:
            - name: packages_id
              description: An array of packages id that need to be shifted
              required: True
              many: array[int]
              paramType: body
    """
```

I have tested with `Postman` and my iOS app and even `Django TestCase` and they all work fine. I'm wondering what `setting/yaml` I need to override for `Swagger` docs to solve the error of `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Please let me know if more information is needed.